# Match CalendarView value with Firebase date value then show within Recycler/CardView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datepicker

I am attempting to implement my own `CardView` within a `Fragment` following previous help from another SO user. I think I have done everything correctly however I am not seeing the expected results and think the fault is elsewhere..

What I have is a `CalendarView` within a `Fragment` which displays the selected date inside a `TextView` using `setOnDateChangeListener`. I then have a hidden `RecyclerView` which has a `CardView` within that, which I am trying to call if the `CalendarView` date matches the date stored in my Firebase database.. Still with me?

I am creating an event schedule, using a form which has event name, date, time, description, all stored as `strings`, see below:

[image]

I have no idea how to retrieve the `push()` value when referencing my database so I have just used the event name for ease at the moment..

Here is what I have, it is a bit all over the place as I have been testing here and there but please let me know if you have questions.. I tried separating my database references to use them in different areas but this did not work either.

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);

        intentEvent = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

        // ------------- firebase --------------
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        uid = currentUser.getUid();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid).child("dogs").child(intentEvent);
        eventReference = databaseReference.child("events");
        dateRef = eventReference.child("date");
        // -------------------------------------

        calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        scheduleTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleTitle);
        noEventPlaceholder = view.findViewById(R.id.noEventPlaceholder);
        addNewEvent = view.findViewById(R.id.addNewEvent);
        eventRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.eventRecycler);

        eventRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        eventLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        eventRecycler.setLayoutManager(eventLayoutManager);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Event> options
                = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Event>()
                .setQuery(databaseReference, Event.class)
                .build();

        eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(options, new EventAdapter.EventCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCardViewClick(Event event) {
                // view event in full?
            }
        });

        if (eventReference == null) {
            addNewEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noEventPlaceholder.setText("Nothing planned for today.. Let's go walkies!");
        } else {
            eventRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        eventRecycler.setAdapter(eventAdapter);

        getEventData();
        dog = new Dog();

        calendarView
                .setOnDateChangeListener(
                        new CalendarView
                                .OnDateChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSelectedDayChange(
                                    @NonNull CalendarView view,
                                    int year,
                                    int month,
                                    int dayOfMonth)
                            {

                                String date
                                        = dayOfMonth + "-"
                                        + (month + 1) + "-" + year;

                                scheduleTitle.setText(date);


                            }
                        });

        // this is an example of what i am trying to do..

        if (String.valueOf(dateRef).equals(scheduleTitle)) {
            eventRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noEventPlaceholder.setText("Nothing planned for today.. Let's go walkies!");
        }
        // ---------------------------------------------

        addNewEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);

                        Intent intentEventForm = new Intent(getContext(), EventForm.class);
                        intentEventForm.putExtra("name", name);
                        startActivity(intentEventForm);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void getEventData() {

        eventReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String eventName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String eventDate = dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                String eventTime = dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue(String.class);
                String eventDescription = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: If I get you right you need to compare different types. With java it's impossible and you need to lead date to a single type. It's possible with `SimpleDateFormat` or `Calendar` or `Date`  classes

Comment: Oh okay! That makes sense.. I actually did that before in another activity, silly me..

Comment: Unsure if its possible to use that with the onDateChangeListener, but will need to look into it

Comment: At `onDateChangeListener` you have year, month and day. The same you get at `date` value from Firebase